# Ошибка 403 при подключении через мобильную сеть

Tags: android, http-status-code-403

Из android приложения при попытке подключения к https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ сервер отвечает 403 ошибкой если на мобилке включен мобильный интернет (билайн, с другими не проверял). Если устройство выходит в сеть через wi-fi, то ответ приходит нормальный. Такая проблема появилась в последнее время, раньше не было. Пробовал подключаться через jsoup и apache http client. Тех. поддержка игнорит. Мне бы понять, это проблема сугубо серверная или здесь может быть что-то ещё? Но тогда как для сервера отличается клиент, выходящий через мобильную сеть от клиента, выходящего через wi-fi?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема на сервере, нужно логи самого сервера чтобы разобраться, там могут и ограничения стоять по IP адресам.

Comment: Я думаю, что режет Beeline - с МТС все нормально приходит Json